# Next.js 13.4 SSG of page with password promt (SSG page with condition)

Tags: next.js, next.js13, mdxjs

I use `.mdx` to store the content and pages are protected with a password prompt (a kind of condition). By visiting the page, it checks the cookie and if no cookie, it asks for the password. If the password is right - then it sets a cookie and shows the contents.

All works on `dev`, but not on the staging.

On the server, this works only with simple text, instead of `.mdx` content.

How to deal with this?

`app/posts/[slug]/page.tsx`

```
import fs from 'fs'
import path from 'path'
import matter from 'gray-matter'

import { MDXRemote } from 'next-mdx-remote/rsc'

import { cookies } from 'next/headers'
import PasswordPromptDialog from '../../components/PasswordPromptDialog'

export async function generateStaticParams(){
    const files = fs.readdirSync(path.join('posts'))
    const paths = files.map(filename => ({
        slug: filename.replace('.mdx', '')
    }))
    return paths
}

function getPost({slug}: {slug: string}){
    const markdownFile = fs.readFileSync(path.join('posts', slug + '.mdx'), 'utf-8')
    const{data: frontMatter, content} = matter(markdownFile)
    return {
        frontMatter,
        slug,
        content
    }
}

export default function Page({ params } :any){
    const cookiesStore = cookies();
    const cookieName = String(process.env.PASSWORD_COOKIE_NAME)
    const isLoggedIn = cookiesStore.has(cookieName)
    const props = getPost( params);

    if (isLoggedIn) {
        return (
            <div className="max-w-container m-auto py-5">
                <article className='prose prose-sm md:prose-base lg:prose-lg prose-slate !prose-invert mx-auto'>
                    <h1 className='text-3xl font-semibold text-center'>{props.frontMatter.title}</h1>

                    <div className="text-lg">
                        <MDXRemote source={props.content} ></MDXRemote>
                    </div>
                </article>
            </div>
        )
    } else {
        return ( 
            <div className="max-w-container m-auto py-5">
                <PasswordPromptDialog />
            </div>
        )
    }
}
```

Server-side logs
[image: Server-side logs]